# how use threads in node for manage two servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, ejs, httpserver

I think that Nodejs only has one thread and I need function a second:4000 server from first server:3000, but when i kill subprocess:4000 also kill general process of aplication.

I am work in local, and now i am use netstat to find the pid of process:4000 to kill.

I need kill second server and the first one continues to work.

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
}
```

server1.js

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('puerto', 3000)

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'))
app.set('view engine','ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    res.render('index')
})

// _________ variable iterable __________
let contador_servidores = 0

app.get('/new', (req, res, next) => {
    //console.log(req.query)

    if( contador_servidores == 0){
        // ______ Declared Second Server __________
        app2 = express()
        app2.set('puerto', 4000)

        app2.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
        res.send('<a href="http://localhost:3000">Return to first server</a>')
    })

    app2.listen( app2.get('puerto'), () => {
    console.log( 'Server2 listen at port',app2.get('puerto') )
    })
    // ______________________
    contador_servidores ++

    res.redirect('http://localhost:4000')
}else{
    res.redirect('http://localhost:4000')
}
    
})

app.listen( app.get('puerto'), () => {
console.log( 'Server listen at port',app.get('puerto') )
})
```

---

folder views/ index.ejs

---

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="/new?port=4000" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">New Server</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as you already know its a single thread, the better way is use `docker` and would be better to use `docker-compose` to handler each server.

Comment: Your OS can't kill threads. It can only kill processes. Your servers run in one process. The only way to kill one server is to write JavaScript logic for it. You can kill a server with `app2.destroy()`.